# Determine identity generation in DB2

Tags: db2, database-schema

In DB2 9.7, when you CREATE a table and specify a column with identity. You can specify the method in which it will handle the generation. You have two choices GENERATED ALWAYS or GENERATED BY DEFAULT.

Once the table has been created how can you tell which method it's using (without performing an insert)?

From the Control Center, I tried to generate the DDL to see how it would generate it, but I'm not certain this is accurate.

Answer (score 2):

You can find all schema-related information in the [DB2 system catalog](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0011297.html). The view [SYSCAT.COLUMNS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001038.html) holds the core data about columns and their properties. To determine whether a column is `GENERATED ALWAYS` or `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` look at the column `GENERATED` in that column.